# Problems to plot this barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm analysing a dataset about the suicides in the world based on age and location. I don't understand why I can't plot this barchart properly. When I access the suicbc variable typing `suicbc` I get a perfect table but the graph is weird.

```
suic <- read_csv("master.csv")

str(suic)
spec_tbl_df [27,820 × 12] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ country           : chr [1:27820] "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" ...
 $ year              : num [1:27820] 1987 1987 1987 1987 1987 ...
 $ sex               : chr [1:27820] "male" "male" "female" "male" ...
 $ age               : chr [1:27820] "15-24 years" "35-54 years" "15-24 years" "75+ years" ...
 $ suicides_no       : num [1:27820] 21 16 14 1 9 1 6 4 1 0 ...
 $ population        : num [1:27820] 312900 308000 289700 21800 274300 ...
 $ suicides/100k pop : num [1:27820] 6.71 5.19 4.83 4.59 3.28 2.81 2.15 1.56 0.73 0 ...
 $ country-year      : chr [1:27820] "Albania1987" "Albania1987" "Albania1987" "Albania1987" ...
 $ HDI for year      : num [1:27820] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ gdp_for_year ($)  : num [1:27820] 2.16e+09 2.16e+09 2.16e+09 2.16e+09 2.16e+09 ...
 $ gdp_per_capita ($): num [1:27820] 796 796 796 796 796 796 796 796 796 796 ...
 $ generation        : chr [1:27820] "Generation X" "Silent" "Generation X" "G.I. Generation"



 suicbc <- suic %>% group_by(Country=country) %>% summarise(Suicides_per_100k=sum(`suicides/100k pop`))
 ggplot(suicbc, aes(x= "Suicides_per_100k", y = "Country"))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")
 str(suicbc)
 tibble [101 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Country          : chr [1:101] "Albania" "Antigua and Barbuda" 
 "Argentina" "Armenia" ...
 $ Suicides_per_100k: num [1:101] 925 179 3895 976 1597 ...
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output/structure of suicbc ?

Comment: @PatrickBormann please see my edit

Comment: wait a sec do you want points or bars? you wrote geom point but you said you want a bar chart I'm a little bit confused, please answer before I go into testing

Comment: @PatrickBormann sorry, corrected

Comment: @PatrickBormann in fact I'm having problems to plot both graphs. The scatterplot is only one point

Comment: The system did not allow this post to be migrated to [SO] because the OP is barred from posting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@whuber If you allow I will answer at least the part about the bar chart:

```
suicbc <- data.frame(Country = factor(c("Alabama", "Yedda", "HighEND")), Values = c(100, 400, 200))
str(suicbc)

ggplot(data = suicbc, aes(x = Country, y = Values)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

You need to insert the stat Attribute in geom_bar and remove the " " around your variable namings
That gives:
[image: bla]

Comment: I did, no? I inserted: geom_bar(stat = "identity")

Comment: Than remove the " "around your variables

Comment: now it worked. Thank you very much!